# Picture when clicked has background I don't want

Tags: highslide

When I click a picture on my page, I get a background frame that I don't want.
Probably a css issue,but I have no clue where to look.
What do I have to change and where? This is the [page](http://www.libralion.com/lenormand.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You have padding added to all table cells in this part of your styles.css file:

```
table th,
table td {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 4px 7px !important;
  padding: 6px 10px;
}
```

This affects the table around the Highslide image. 

You can fix it by adding this to your highslide.css file:

```
.highslide-container table td {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks RoadRash! I just saw this comment now. Thank you so much! it is all good now! You made my day! :)