# How to remove unexplained shadow around pictures?

Tags: image, shadow

I have got a weird shadow around my pictures on [my webpage](http://www.libralion.com/lenormand.htm). I've already searched in the css, but I can't seem to find the reason for this behavior.

Comment: Sounds like a haunting to me :p

Comment: The browsers I tested are: Chrome, IE9 and FF
They all show this weird shadow.

Comment: You have background image on popup table td that uses sprite. Adjust size of elements

Comment: Justinas in what file do I do that?

Comment: Ok found the answer. Didn't see this answer until now. I think Stackoverflow is a bit confusing for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908433/picture-when-clicked-has-background-i-dont-want/18016616?noredirect=1#18016616